# Selectize finds only the words that start with the given string

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

Why does Selectize show only the words that start with the given string and not the ones that contain it?

I want to show the matches that contain the specified string, not only those that start with it (the default behavior, I think).

I have reproduced the example from the web and it does not have the same behavior. Why?

https://selectize.dev/docs/demos/single-item-select

My result:

[image: My Test]

Selectize example result:

[image: Selectize Web page]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title> TEST</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/css/selectize.default.min.css"
          integrity="sha512-pTaEn+6gF1IeWv3W1+7X7eM60TFu/agjgoHmYhAfLEU8Phuf6JKiiE8YmsNC0aCgQv4192s4Vai8YZ6VNM6vyQ=="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.15.2/js/selectize.min.js"
          integrity="sha512-IOebNkvA/HZjMM7MxL0NYeLYEalloZ8ckak+NDtOViP7oiYzG5vn6WVXyrJDiJPhl4yRdmNAG49iuLmhkUdVsQ=="
          crossorigin="anonymous"
          referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select id="normalize">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Awesome</option>
        <option value="2">Beast</option>
        <option value="3">Compatible</option>
        <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
        <option value="5">Nikola</option>
        <option value="6">Selectize</option>
        <option value="7">Javascript</option>
      </select>
      <script>
      $('#normalize').selectize();
      </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The CDN link was not working properly. I have downloaded the latest release from Github and now it is working.

[Selectize Github](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js)